# Load image passed as props react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I am trying to load image from props i am getting the following error
**warning: failed prop type: invalid prop `source` supplied to `image`**
Here is my code

src/components/common/Header.js

```
<View style={viewStyle}>
  <Text style={textStyle}>{props.children}</Text>
  <Image style={{height:25, width:25}} source={props.imageUri} />
</View>
```

src/index.js

```
<Header imageUri='../../images/logout.png'>My App</Header>
```

and the image is at path src/images/logout.png

please help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

your **source** is wrong.

It should use **uri** properties.

Either you use require:

```
<Image source={require('.../../images/logout.png')} />
```

in turn, you can then require this prop too

```
<Image source={require(props.imageUri)} />
```

Or you use the Uri as is:

```
<Image source={{uri: props.imageUri }} />
```

[Refer to the documentation for more details here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html)

Comment: what should be the PropType to be passed in?

Comment: I have tried to do this but I am not being able to achieve a component independent of name and thus quite frustrated by myself. Please help me for resolving javascript into react native. WHenever I implement the links inside it ends upto error throwing that source is invalid or invalid call

Answer (score 27):

> As the [React Native Documentation says](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html), all your images sources need to be loaded before compiling your bundle.

Adding a simple image in React Native should be like this:

```js
<Image source={require('./path_to_your_image.png')} />
```

Let's say you have this:

```js
const slides = {
  car: './car.png',
  phone: '../phone.png',
}
```

Then you pass `slides` as a parameter but still, you won't be able to use it like this (even though logically should work):

```js
<Image source={require(props.car)} />
```

**Use `require()` inside the `sildes{}`**

```js
const slides = {
  car: require('./car.png'),
  phone: require('../phone.png'),
}
```

And then use it like this:

```js
<Image source={props.car}/>
```

Answer (score 9):

Using the below method gives `error` in react-native:

```
<Image style={{height:25, width:25}} source={require(props.imageUri)} />
```

Instead use:

```
<Image style={{height:25, width:25}} source={props.imageUri}/>
```

And pass the below code as imageUri prop from the `Parent` component.

```
require('./public/images/image.png')
```

It has worked for me and hope this will help others.

Answer (score 7):

you can set source of image from props like this :
in component :

```
<Image source={props.path} >
```

and pass source to component like this:
in parent :

```
<
.
.
path={require("../assets/images/icon.svg")}
.
.
>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a local image path the syntax is

```
<Image style={{height:25, width:25}} source={require(props.imageUri)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Image
            source={this.props.imgUri}
            style={{
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              resizeMode: 'contain',
            }}
          />
```

call it

```
 <StyledInput text="NAME" imgUri={require('../assets/userIcon.png')} ></StyledInput>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place Image directly in the Component, as a prop children.

```
<ComponentA>
        <Image source={require('./src/assets/localisation-icon.svg')} />
</ComponentA>
```

The Component A will be composed of

```
function ComponentA(props) {
    return (<View> {props.children} </View>); 
 }
```

This will render the image.

Answer (score 0):

in your express.js server, set up a [static directory](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) containing any `image.jpg`:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../path_to/..', staticImages)))
```

react native component:

```
return <Image source={{ uri: `http://192.168.0.1:3345/${'image.jpg'}`}} />
```