# The picture can't be displayed, what is the reason?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import GridList from '@material-ui/core/GridList';
import GridListTile from '@material-ui/core/GridListTile';
import tileData from './tileData';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  gridList: {
    width: 500,
    height: 450,
  },
}));

export default function ImageGridList() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  console.log(tileData);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <GridList cellHeight={160} className={classes.gridList} cols={3}>
        {tileData.map(tile => (
          <GridListTile key={tile.img} cols={tile.cols || 1}>
            <img src={tile.img} alt={tile.title} />
          </GridListTile>
        ))}
      </GridList>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
const tileData = [
  {
    img: '/static/images/grid-list/breakfast.jpg',
    title: 'Breakfast',
    author: 'jill111',
    cols: 2,
    featured: true,
  },
  {
    img: '/static/images/grid-list/burgers.jpg',
    title: 'Tasty burger',
    author: 'director90',
  },
  {
    img: '/static/images/grid-list/camera.jpg',
    title: 'Camera',
    author: 'Danson67',
  },
  {
    img: '/static/images/grid-list/morning.jpg',
    title: 'Morning',
    author: 'fancycrave1',
    featured: true,
  },
  {
    img: '/static/images/grid-list/hats.jpg',
    title: 'Hats',
    author: 'Hans',
  },
  {
    img: '/static/images/grid-list/honey.jpg',
    title: 'Honey',
    author: 'fancycravel',
  },
  {
    img: '/static/images/grid-list/vegetables.jpg',
    title: 'Vegetables',
    author: 'jill111',
    cols: 2,
  },
  {
    img: '/static/images/grid-list/plant.jpg',
    title: 'Water plant',
    author: 'BkrmadtyaKarki',
  },
  {
    img: '/static/images/grid-list/mushroom.jpg',
    title: 'Mushrooms',
    author: 'PublicDomainPictures',
  },
  {
    img: '/static/images/grid-list/olive.jpg',
    title: 'Olive oil',
    author: 'congerdesign',
  },
  {
    img: '/static/images/grid-list/star.jpg',
    title: 'Sea star',
    cols: 2,
    author: '821292',
  },
  {
    img: '/static/images/grid-list/bike.jpg',
    title: 'Bike',
    author: 'danfador',
  },
];

export default tileData;
```

src={tile.img}, Seems like this is wrong.I tried using the require method, still not working.
Sorry, in order to make up enough words, I repeated.
Sorry, in order to make up enough words, I repeated.
Sorry, in order to make up enough words, I repeated.
Sorry, in order to make up enough words, I repeated.
Sorry, in order to make up enough words, I repeated.
Sorry, in order to make up enough words, I repeated.

Comment: at least you should provide what is `tile.img` because looks fine how you are trying to put the img.

Comment: Please check this [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42922455/load-image-passed-as-props-react-native/42922627#42922627)

Comment: have you `import image from 'path' add the image location?

Comment: Hey, I think there is something wrong with the path,
it should be something like "../../static/images/grid-list/breakfast.jpg"

or you can do this also

> import Image1 from "../static/images/grid-list/bike.jpg";
then use like : 

>  {
    img: Image1,
    title: 'Breakfast',
    author: 'jill111',
    cols: 2,
    featured: true,
  }

Comment: no something like "../../static/images/grid-list/breakfast.jpg",you can try it locally.

Answer (score 0):

in you tileData file try this:

```
const breakfast = '..relativePath../static/images/grid-list/breakfast.jpg'

const tileData = [
  {
    img: breakfast,
    title: 'Breakfast',
    author: 'jill111',
    cols: 2,
    featured: true,
  }
]
```