# Image is not being displayed whiloe using the Local File Path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I place my local image file in the dummy-data.js file?

```
const HProduct{
 constructor(){
this.id:id;
this.title:title;
this.image:image;
this.description:description;
this.price:price;

}

}
```

If placing the path is like this:

```
new Product(

'p6',

'Carrots',
require('../assets/my-apps-images/carrots.jpg'),

"The carrot is a root vegetable, usually orange in color, though purple, black, red, white, and yellow cultivars exist.",

70,
)
```

How can I call that  component?

Like this??

`<Image  source={props.image} />`

I get a warning and a black display of the image. Please check it out. May be I am clear now
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please let us know what package or framework you are using? Is this React?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Image source={require("../assets/my-apps-images/carrots.jpg")}/>
```

Comment: thanks, I can get that

What if if my Images are in another component and I am using the props to get all so should a parent component would rendering all the images like this?
```
<ProductItem>
...
<Image source={props.image}/>

</ProductItem>
```

Should we render like that? if that is so then black image is returned

Comment: {
<ProductItem> 
... 
<Image source={props.image}/> 
</ProductItem>
}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42922455/load-image-passed-as-props-react-native