# Getting an image from route.paramns in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to make a profiles screen for my members of the group.
My idea is make just one font for the four screen using route params to set all informations, like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.ident1} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile', {
    Nome: 'Ângelo J. da Rosa', Resto: ['19 Anos', 'Cocal do Sul - SC'], Foto: '../../assets/angelo.jpeg'
    })}>
    <Text style={{ fontSize: 20,fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Angelo</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

But when I am trying to get the image from the folder using the path that I got from the paramns (Foto), i get an error and not know how to proceed

My screen font:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function Profile({ route, navigation }) {
    const { Nome, Resto, Foto } = route.params;

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <Image
                style={styles.image}
                source={require({Foto})}
            />
            <Text style={[styles.headline]}>{"\n"}{Nome}</Text>

            <View style={[styles.views, styles.ident1]}>,
                <Text style={[styles.desc]}>{Resto[0]}</Text>
                <Text style={[styles.desc]}>{Resto[1]}</Text>
                <Text style={[styles.desc]}>{Resto[2]}</Text>
                <Text style={[styles.desc]}>{Resto[3]}</Text>
                <Text style={[styles.desc]}>{Resto[4]}</Text>
             </View>
        </View>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing one mistake while passing the image path. You can follow the below code:

```
    Foto: require('../../assets/angelo.jpeg')
```

And use it as a prop like this :

```
<Image source={Foto}/>
```

NOTE: For more information please refer this: [Load image passed as props react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42922455/load-image-passed-as-props-react-native)