# How to load a image path through props in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

how to load imported image path to img tag src  from the component props. please help

```
import amy from "./amy.jpg";
<AvatarProfileIcon icon="amy" />

 <img src={props.icon} />
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/load-icon-through-props-in-img-src-9qzox5

Comment: Possible duplicate: *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42922455/load-image-passed-as-props-react-native*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your imported image inside curly braces `{}` instead of double quotes `""` since they are being used for strings.

```
import amy from "./amy.jpg";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AvatarProfileIcon icon={amy} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit Load icon through props in img src (forked)]

Comment: it won't work :(

Comment: I added a live demo

Answer (score 1):

the string can't indicate variable's name.
change your code like this.

```
function objectfromstring(string){
  switch(string){
    case 'amy' : return amy
    case 'andrew' : return andrew
    case 'ava' : return ava
    case 'ben' : return ben
    case 'brian' : return brian
    default : return amy
  }
}

function Avataruserprofile(props) {
  return (
    <div className="avataruser">
      <img src={objectfromstring(props.icon)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

- you mistyped your code in your html code(not amy but ami) sandbox

I added code
https://codesandbox.io/s/load-icon-through-props-in-img-src-forked-wc5xp1

Answer (score 0):

```
import "./styles.css";
import AvatarProfileIcon from "./AvatarProfileIcon";
import amy from "./amy.jpg";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <AvatarProfileIcon icon={amy} />
   </div>
  );
 }
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/load-icon-through-props-in-img-src-forked-qekmt1)