# How to append the value of a variable in a Image uri | React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
const Stories = ({
    id, 
    profileImg, 
    text, 
}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
                <Image
                //   source={{ uri: {profileImg}}
                />

      </ScrollView> 
    </View>
  )
}
```

I am trying to use the value of a variable as a URI in react Native but its not working. I had tried putting the value of that parameter in {} like {profileImg} but it failed and the image is not rendering on the page

Comment: The Value of the parameter is a string for example = "https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.3f7189662f19f8318fc75252deee723a?rik=Qa956Np1tp8Zcg&riu=http%3a%2f%2f1000logos.net%2fwp-content%2fuploads%2f2017%2f06%2fTwitter-Logo.png&ehk=6ekNd2ZmhpvFDGRZF19QcumP9fb8pZRkwrbFbK%2bpULA%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0"

Comment: This is an duplicate question. Please check this existing question's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42922627/14359374

Comment: Also the link you shared looks like it is an external image source. So, you need to add ***`http://`*** or ***`https://`*** before your url's domain name.

Comment: it should be like this `source={{ uri: profileImg}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
const baseUrl = 'https://whatever.com'
const valueToBeAdded = "userProfile";
const profileImg = `${baseUrl}/${valueToBeAdded}`

   source={{ uri: {profileImg}}
```

this should work